# Can't visit site after switching on Language Detection 'Session' in combination with Ip to locale

Tags: i18n-l10n, sessions

[My site](http://landberg.at) is in a kind of a loop? I can't login anymore and visit the site? http://landberg.at/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/en/user

What do i have to do. Its a combination with IP to local and Language Detection 'Session'

- How do i disable Language Detection 'Session' from mySql database manually?
- i already disabled IP to local module from database...

I really need my site back as soon as possible.

Thanks!

**Update:**

I solved it by entering ?language=en behind my URL. After this i was able to login again.

Comment: Do you use drush? Have you tried disabling the module via drush?

Comment: no i disabled it directly in mySQL with `UPDATE system SET status='0' WHERE name='module_name';`

Comment: It is possible that the module is still cached. Have you tried 
`DELETE FROM cache_bootstrap WHERE cid='system_list';` ?

Comment: yes i did that too! But still i can't visit the site. I want manually disable Language Detection 'Session' in database but i don't know where it is?

Comment: once you are able, be sure to include your solution as an answer and 'accept' it so this question does not remain unanswered

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by entering ?language=en behind my URL. After this i was able to login and visit my site again.